# Google Crawl Thousands Of Link On Same Page

Tags: web-crawler

I have created a page with thousands of links on it for google to crawl it and index all the data in those thousands of pages accessible through links on the single page.

I am checking google search results after 4 days of setting this up.

It seems that google has crawled only a few links out of the thousands as only few appear in search results.

I even put the Site: filter while searching on google.

Does any one have any idea why this happens. . Why all those thousand pages are not indexed by google but only a few randomly picked ??

Comment: Can you tell us what are the thousands of webpages? Do you host your own server and did you open it for 4 days? google takes time to crawl the WWW.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out this google page:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=34439

The essence of google crawler is that it will crawl your site more if you site is important.

And the meaning of important, is according to the number of hyperlink linked to and from your website. And you can imagine a website such as yahoo will have high rank. Please check out [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) algorithm.

You may also want to check out this [webmaster guide](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769) from google to help get your site crawled more.